# NotSupportedException in Asp.NET Core MVC Razor Pages Rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I recently created a small ASP.Net Core MVC project, and placed all my .cshtml files in the Views directory. Then I using the following code in Startup.cs to change where Razor searches for the view files:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => {
    //{2} is area, {1} is controller, {0} is the action    
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/{1}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
});
```

The .cshtml files map to a corresponding controller name, where all controllers contain a default "Index" action that simply returns the associated View().

This is the current routing:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Index}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

In my eyes this configuration should work, however a "NotSupportedException" is being thrown by Razor whenever I try to invoke any page, and I am unsure how to debug this:

```
NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageBase.EnsureRenderedBodyOrSections()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync<TFilter, TFilterAsync>()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I looked at the source code of EnsureRenderedBodyOrSections(), which is simply the following:

```
public override void EnsureRenderedBodyOrSections() {
    //This will never be called by MVC. MVC only calls this method on layout pages, and a Page can never be a layout page.
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

MVC is apparently calling the function when it's not supposed to. What exactly is the issue that's at play here?

PS: This is the project on GitHub: https://github.com/mathusummut/nemesys-stackoverflow

Comment: So you have a controller named Index? `template: "{controller=Index}` in your routing?

Comment: Yes, and it is meant to show the homepage which is Index.cshtml.

Comment: Yeah. A github link would probably be helpful.

Comment: @MathuSumMut May I ask why you want to change where Razor looks for Views? Why not just let it place them in their default location?

Comment: This is because I would have to create a directory for every .cshtml file using the default routing (at least, that's what Razor wanted me to do as it couldn't find my Views). I have a controller for every .cshtml file.

Comment: A github link is now given

Comment: @MathuSumMut When you create the controller, you can right click the controller method `Index` and choose `Create View`, I am unsure of why you don't go this route, and then paste your HTML into your Views or add HTML to the newly created View.

Comment: I was migrating a small project that didn't use MVC to MVC, and I wanted to keep the configuration in a similar manner.

Comment: @MathuSumMut Ok, I can see your reasoning but the layout of an MVC project is going to be different than the layout of a non-MVC project, I would think it would be easier to just learn the MVC way.

Comment: It appears you're trying to use Razor Pages as views for an MVC application. If you're returning a `View(...)` result from a `Controller`, you should not be using a Page for the view. A Page is a `.cshtml` file with a `@page` directive at the top. These technologies are meant to be mutually exclusive for a given request path. You can use them both in the same application, but not in the same request. I would recommend removing the `@page` directive from your views and going from there.

Comment: @briman0094 Add this as an answer, and I will accept it because it worked. :)

Comment: I'll write it up as one now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `EnsureRenderedBodyOrSections` method is being called is because you're returning a `View()` result from a Controller, and this method is part of the rendering lifecycle for **Views**. Your Razor files, however, have `@page` directives at the top, which makes them into Page files for Razor **Pages**.

While you can use MVC Views and Razor Pages in the same application, they cannot be mixed for one **request path**. If you remove the `@page` directive from your View files, they will be compiled as Razor Views and not Razor Pages, so you will not get a `NotSupportedException`.

As a side note, I would recommend removing the line `options.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();` and keep the default view location, so that you can use the `Views/{Controller}/{Action}` view location in the future while still being able to have a view file named `Views/{Controller}`. That way as you add more functionality to the now-MVC application, you can do so using traditional MVC patterns.

Comment: Thanks! I did take your advice on the options thing, it is now `options.ViewLocationFormats.Insert(0, "/Views/{1}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);` instead